# How check intent activity status on whatsapp video call

Tags: java, android, whatsapp

I'm creating the Intent() with a WhatsApp call in my Activity, but I don't know how to see what state this call is in.

I want to know if it's calling or if it was finished calling and retry again.

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
String data = "content://com.android.contacts/data/" + Long.toString(_ID);
String type = "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.com.whatsapp.video.call";
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(data), type);
intent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

I trying see the status user "onActivityResulty" but if you do not answer the call this event does not execute, I guess it is because the call still does not end, because inside whatsapp gives me the option to make this call again.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    // Create Intent() / Call again
}
```

The goal is to make sure that when a call ends or idle the app will call back automatically only.

If you can give me some help I would appreciate it.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I tried to implement similar functionality in one of the applications i've worked on.

I didn't majorly focus on implementing whatsapp call, but i somehow wanted to handle my application when User hangs up the call so i tried this.

```
private class VoiceCallListener implements CallListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallEnded(Call endedCall) {
        //call ended by either party
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallEstablished(Call establishedCall) {
        //incoming call was picked up
    }

    @Override
    public void onCallProgressing(Call progressingCall) {
        //call is ringing
    }

    @Override
    public void onShouldSendPushNotification(Call call, List<PushPair> pushPairs) {
        //don't worry about this right now
    }
}
```

You can refer this [page](https://developers.sinch.com/docs/build-a-simple-android-voip-calling-app-with-sinch) if you want more information on implementation as it give a very generic overview of how calls are implemented, let me know if that helps.

Complete code is available on this [page](https://github.com/sinch/app-app-calling-android)